# Is Super Mario Run's full version shared between device accounts?

Tags: android, super-mario-run

We have an android device that each member of my family logs into. They have separate android logins. I've downloaded Super Mario Run, and they can all play Super Mario Run on the device.

I've been thinking about buying the full version, but will everyone have access to it, or just me? Is there a way for all of us to get it?

Comment: Are they all using the same Google Play account?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you all share a Google Play account, you only need to purchase one copy.

Nintendo has structured SMR such that you buy the game per platform, not per  Nintendo account. This is also the reason you have to buy the game again if you wish to play cross-platform.

Usually, if you are switching Nintendo accounts on the game, you should have no issues. However, every once in a while you may need to tap the "**Restore Purchases**" button.